# Configure Apache tomcat in xampp with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, jsp, tomcat, xampp

I am new to jsp. When executing java servlets normally we use Apache tomcat.Anyway I already have installed tomcat which comes with Xampp.I tried to configure existing tomcat server with eclipse,but failed getting an error from eclipse saying problems with port.But tomcat is the only process that is running on that port.

Does anyone know how to configure?

Comment: Can you tell what is the error you are getting?

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tomcat

Comment: Error says another process is currently using the port.but xampp apache tomcat is the onl process running on that port.When I stoped tomcat from xampp control panel eclipse does not give previous messagge and it says server is started.but when I type localhost:8080/ and hit enter browser says file is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, it seems that you only must run one of servers, I mean from Apache Tomcat or Eclipse Tomcat, so if you want to use Eclipse Tomcat, you have to stop Apache Tomcat. I hope it helps although maybe you got the answer